# No module named mem_profile

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pip, generator

I'm using this program to measure the time and memory used by two functions and compare which is better for processing a large amount of data. My understanding is that to measure the memory usage we need the `mem_profile` module, but during the `pip install mem_profile`  it gave me the error `No module named mem_profile`.

```
import mem_profile
import random
import time

names = ['Kiran','King','John','Corey']
majors = ['Math','Comps','Science']

print 'Memory (Before): {}Mb'.format(mem_profile.memory_usage_resource())

def people_list(num_people):
    results = []
    for i in num_people:
        person = {
                    'id':i,
                    'name': random.choice(names),
                    'major':random.choice(majors)
                  }
        results.append(person)
    return results

def people_generator(num_people):
    for i in xrange(num_people):
        person = {
                    'id':i,
                    'name': random.choice(names),
                    'major':random.choice(majors)
                  }
        yield person

t1 = time.clock()
people = people_list(10000000)
t2 = time.clock()


# t1 = time.clock()
# people = people_generator(10000000)
# t2 = time.clock()

print 'Memory (After): {}Mb'.format(mem_profile.memory_usage_resource())
print 'Took {} Seconds'.format(t2-t1)
```

What has caused this error? And are there any alternative packages I could use instead?

Comment: I literally just watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD05uGo_sVI, and I see the exact same code here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this for calculating time:

```
import time

time_start = time.time()
#run your code
time_elapsed = (time.time() - time_start)
```

As referenced by the Python documentation:

> time.time() → float
> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.
> The specific date of the epoch and the handling of leap seconds is
> platform dependent. On Windows and most Unix systems, the epoch is
> January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC) and leap seconds are not counted
> towards the time in seconds since the epoch. This is commonly referred
> to as Unix time. To find out what the epoch is on a given platform,
> look at gmtime(0).
>
> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point
> number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1
> second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it
> can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has
> been set back between the two calls.
>
> The number returned by time() may be converted into a more common time
> format (i.e. year, month, day, hour, etc…) in UTC by passing it to
> gmtime() function or in local time by passing it to the localtime()
> function. In both cases a struct_time object is returned, from which
> the components of the
> calendar date may be accessed as attributes.

**Reference**: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

---

Use this for calculating memory:

```
import resource

resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

**Reference**: http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html

Use this if you using python 3.x:

**Reference**:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: don't use time.clock().  it is misleading and also deprecated.  The reference you quoted is outdated and has been updated in newer versions of python3 documentation

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock). @CoreyGoldberg

Comment: I don't have much experience in python as of now i'm working on python 2.7 so i found solution on the basis of that. i agree with you @CoreyGoldberg when using python 3.x.

Comment: yes that.  time.clock() also has different behavior on Windows vs other platforms.  I suggest removing this answer

Comment: this answer provides bad advice for timing code, no matter which version of python you are using

Comment: You can use `time.time()`, it returns the exact number of seconds (a `float`) since the Epoch. So
`import time; t1 = time.time();
t2 = time.time(); print(t2)`
would output the elapsed time since the creation of `t1`.

Answer (score 20):

1)First import module

```
pip install memory_profiler
```

2)include it in your code like this

```
import memory_profiler as mem_profile
```

3)change code

`mem_profile.memory_usage_psutil()` to `memory_usage()`

4)convert you print statements like this

```
print('Memory (Before): ' + str(mem_profile.memory_usage()) + 'MB' )
print('Memory (After) : ' + str(mem_profile.memory_usage()) + 'MB')
print ('Took ' + str(t2-t1) + ' Seconds')
```

5)you will have something like this code:

```
import memory_profiler as mem_profile
import random
import time

names = ['John', 'Corey', 'Adam', 'Steve', 'Rick', 'Thomas']
majors = ['Math', 'Engineering', 'CompSci', 'Arts', 'Business']

# print('Memory (Before): {}Mb '.format(mem_profile.memory_usage_psutil()))
print('Memory (Before): ' + str(mem_profile.memory_usage()) + 'MB' )

def people_list(num_people):
    result = []
    for i in range(num_people):
        person = {
                    'id': i,
                    'name': random.choice(names),
                    'major': random.choice(majors)
                }
        result.append(person)
    return result

def people_generator(num_people):
    for i in range(num_people):
        person = {
                    'id': i,
                    'name': random.choice(names),
                    'major': random.choice(majors)
                }
        yield person

# t1 = time.clock()
# people = people_list(1000000)
# t2 = time.clock()

t1 = time.clock()
people = people_generator(1000000)
t2 = time.clock()

# print 'Memory (After) : {}Mb'.format(mem_profile.memory_usage_psutil())
print('Memory (After) : ' + str(mem_profile.memory_usage()) + 'MB')

# print 'Took {} Seconds'.format(t2-t1)
print ('Took ' + str(t2-t1) + ' Seconds')
```

Now it work fine i m using python 3.6 and its working without any error.

Comment: Hey, the profiling for generator is misleading, as nothing was "generated" in people_generator.

Answer (score 13):

Was going through the same tutorial and encountered the same problem. But upon further research, I discovered the author of the tutorial used a package called `memory_profiler`, whose main file he changed to `mem_profile`, which he imported in the code tutorial.

Just go ahead and do `pip install memory_profiler`. Copy and rename the file to `mem_profile.py` in your working directory and you should be fine. If you are on Windows, make sure you install the dependent `psutil` package as well.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to *[Adebayo Ibro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7346745/adebayo-ibro)*'s answer above. Do the following :

- In terminal, run `$ pip install memory_profiler`
- In your script, replace `import mem_profile` with `import memory_profiler as mem_profile`
- In your script, replace **all** `mem_profile.memory_usage_resource()` with `mem_profile.memory_usage()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

That module is hand written (not in python packages).
I got this from Corey Schafer's comment in his youtube video.
Just save this code as the module's name:

```
from pympler import summary, muppy
import psutil
import resource
import os
import sys

def memory_usage_psutil():
    # return the memory usage in MB
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20)
    return mem

def memory_usage_resource():
    rusage_denom = 1024.
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        # ... it seems that in OSX the output is different units ...
        rusage_denom = rusage_denom * rusage_denom
    mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / rusage_denom
    return mem
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem. I solved it installing `memory_profiler` (`$ pip install -U memory_profiler`), and them modify the program as follows:

```
import memory_profiler
...
print('Memory (Before): {}Mb'.format(memory_profiler.memory_usage()))
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of python 3.8 updates since time.clock() was removed, and print() has evolved.

Thanks everyone for this discussion, and definitely thanks to Corey Schafer great video.

```
import memory_profiler as mem_profile
import random
import time

names = ['John', 'Corey', 'Adam', 'Steve', 'Rick', 'Thomas']
majors = ['Math', 'Engineering', 'CompSci', 'Arts', 'Business']

print(f'Memory (Before): {mem_profile.memory_usage()}Mb')

def people_list(num_people):
    result = []
    for i in range(num_people):
        person = {
                    'id': i,
                    'name': random.choice(names),
                    'major': random.choice(majors)
                }
        result.append(person)
    return result

def people_generator(num_people):
    for i in range(num_people):
        person = {
                    'id': i,
                    'name': random.choice(names),
                    'major': random.choice(majors)
                }
        yield person

# t1 = time.process_time()
# people = people_list(1000000)
# t2 = time.process_time()

t1 = time.process_time()
people = people_generator(1000000)
t2 = time.process_time()


print(f'Memory (After): {mem_profile.memory_usage()}Mb')

print(f'Took {t2-t1} Seconds')
```

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same tutorial
the library name is `memory_profiler`
in order to install, you can use the following

```
pip install -U memory_profiler
```

to importing

```
import memory_profiler
```

note: the library does not have `memory_usage_resource` function
but you can use `memory_usage` with the same functionality.
instead of using `clock()` function use `time()` function

```
import memory_profiler
import random
import time

names=['John', 'Jane', 'Adam','Steve', 'Rick','George','Paul','Bill','Bob']
majors=['Math','Engineering','ComSic','Arts','Stuck Broker']

print ('Memory (Before): {} MB'.format(memory_profiler.memory_usage()))
#using list
def people_list(num_people):
    result = []
    for i in range(num_people):
        person={
            'id':i,
            'name':random.choice(names),
            'major':random.choice(majors)
        }
        result.append(person)
    return result


#using generators
def people_generator(num_people):
    for i in range(num_people):
        person={
            'id':i,
            'name':random.choice(names),
            'major':random.choice(majors)
        }
        yield person


# t1=time.time()
# people_list(1000000)
# t2=time.time()

t1=time.time()
people_generator(1000000)
t2=time.time()

print('Memory (After): {} MB'.format(memory_profiler.memory_usage()))
print ('Took {} seconds'.format(t2-t1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simple with sys

```
    import sys
    ...
    print ('Memory (Before): {0}Mb'.format(sys.getsizeof([])))
```

Answer (score -1):

> during the pip install mem_profile it gave me error No module named mem_profile.

by default, pip will download packages from PyPI.  No package exists on PyPI named "mem_profile", so of course you will get an error.

---

for timing blocks of code, the `timeit` module is what you want to use:
https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html